# Deleting the minimum value recursively from a matrix using a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, recursion

I have a matrix like

```
 ID     885038  885039  885040  885041  885042  885043  Class
weights 0       0.005   0       0.018   0       0.007   N/A
1267359 2       0       0       0       0       1       1
1295720 2       0       1       0       0       1       1
1295721 2       0       0       0       0       1       1
1295723 2       0       0       0       0       1       1
1295724 2       0       1       0       1       1       1
```

I want to eliminate each column one by one from the matrix based on the weights. At each iteration, the column with minimum weights value should be removed.

```
Such that iteration 1: 885041,885040,885042 (columns would be removed)
          iteration 2: 885039 (removed)
          iteration 3: 885043 (removed)
          iteration 4: 885041 (removed)
```

The code written for this task is

```
library(readr)
dummy <- read_csv("dummy.csv")
dummy <- t(dummy)
colnames(dummy) <- dummy[1,]
dummy <- dummy[-1,]

for (i in 1:ncol(dummy))
{
  min <- as.matrix(which.min(dummy[,1] == min(dummy[,1])))
  filter <- row.names(min)
  data<- dummy[setdiff(rownames(dummy),filter),]
  data <- data[-1,]
  print(ncol(data))
}
```

However, it gives an output

```
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
```

I want the number of columns printed like

```
6
5
4
3
2
```

Is there a way to use some apply functions here?

Comment: The matrix that you provide is not very clear. Looks like column "class" should be in the rows, so after the transpose you have a matrix with column names (ID, weights, 1267359, 1295720,1295721 , 1295723,1295724) ? Anyway, what you do in your loop is always overwriting data with dummy / t(dummy). Therefore it will always iteratively return 6 or 5.

Comment: @Arno, I changed the code "data<- dummy[setdiff(rownames(dummy),filter),]" but now the error shows 6,6,6,6,6,6

Comment: I used the same matrix and the same code, and I am getting the same output. @Sotos. I think I have provided a reproducible example only

Comment: FYI, [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: I have provided a minimal example. I used the same matrix to run this code which gave me a series of sixes, instead of decreasing the length at every iteration.

Comment: @sp2, the same issue remains: "data " is always overwritten with "dummy" which does not change in your loop, so it will always give the same results. What you can do is adding: dummy <- dummy[-1,]. I do not have time to improve the code, but sure it can be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seem to be a matrix of string. You need to convert them into numeric.
A reproducible example would be nice as Sotos asked you. We can't know from your way of providing the example if your data type is of string or numeric.

```
# reproduce your data for you
df = data.frame(matrix(data=
  c("weights",0,       0.005,   0,       0.018,   0,       0.007,   "N/A",
    1267359,2,       0,       0,       0,       0,       1,       1,
    1295720,2,       0,       1,       0,       0,       1,       1,
    1295721,2,       0,       0,       0,       0,       1,       1,
    1295723,2,       0,       0,       0,       0,       1,       1,
    1295724,2,       0,       1,       0,       1,       1,       1), 
  ncol = 8, byrow = TRUE
), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(df) = c("ID","885038",  "885039",  "885040",  "885041",  "885042",  "885043",  "Class")
df2 = df[, !colnames(df)%in%c("Class")]

# dummy <- read_csv("dummy.csv")
dummy = df2
dummy <- t(dummy)
colnames(dummy) <- dummy[1,]
dummy <- dummy[-1,]

# "dummy" is a matrix of string. You need a data.frame of numeric.
#        weights 1267359 1295720 1295721 1295723 1295724
# 885038 "0"     "2"     "2"     "2"     "2"     "2"    
# 885039 "0.005" "0"     "0"     "0"     "0"     "0"    
# 885040 "0"     "0"     "1"     "0"     "0"     "1"    
# 885041 "0.018" "0"     "0"     "0"     "0"     "0"    
# 885042 "0"     "0"     "0"     "0"     "0"     "1"    
# 885043 "0.007" "1"     "1"     "1"     "1"     "1"   

class(dummy) # [1] "matrix"
dummy = data.frame(dummy)
dummy$weights = as.numeric(as.character( dummy$weights))
class(dummy$weights) # [1] "numeric"

data = dummy
for (i in 1:ncol(dummy))
{
  rowMin = which.min(data$weights)
  print(paste(nrow(data),rownames(data)[rowMin]))
  data = data[-rowMin,]
}

# [1] "6 885038"
# [1] "5 885040"
# [1] "4 885042"
# [1] "3 885039"
# [1] "2 885043"
# [1] "1 885041"
```

Comment: Thankyou @Stok. But At the first iteration, there are three minimum weights 885038, 885040 and 885042